# 206.2 kB (204.8 kB loaded) prepended in LONGBLOB value

Tags: php, mysql, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm saving files in my MySQL database on a LONGBLOB column and when I perform a select in my IDE I notice some of the base64 file content has the message `206.2 kB (204.8 kB loaded)` prepended to it.

I'm using PHP to prepare the data and perform the inserts to the db:

```
$file = file_get_contents('path/to/file.pdf');
$encodedFile = base64_encode($file);
```

Does anyone know how is this happening?

Comment: Note this is also a problem in other JetBrains IDEs and other databases. I'm seeing it in latest PyCharm with Postgresql on xml fields. The actual values are stored correctly in database, it's only an UI bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out this is being imposed by the IDE I'm using, which is PHPStorm, to avoid memory exhaustion on the computer.

If I use mysql cli on the terminal all values show fine.

Comment: Thanks! I just had this happen in PyCharm, and I couldn't figure out what the heck was going on :)

Answer (score 4):

Data is not fully loaded using the IDE.
Change the value in the PHPStorm/Datagrip settings (or another JetBrains IDE)

```
File -> Settings.

Database -> Data Views -> Maximum Length in Bytes.
```

Set the value in bytes:

```
5242880
```

(5 megabytes)

You can set a higher value if you are missing 5 megabytes